# Segue from storyboard to .xib

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a storyboardViewController (UITableViewController) and 1 item of that table is 'USERS' (UIButton) but I need to join it with a .XIB, this .XIB is in the same proyect.

I can not to do a segue between the UIButton with the .XIB.
Pls Helpme :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44675813/3937

Answer (score 0):

Connect the `UIButton` with an `@IBAction` and add the following code to the action method to present a new `UIViewController` that is set up inside a .xib file.

```
@IBAction func handleButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let viewControllerInXib = ViewControllerInXib(nibName: "ViewControllerXibName", bundle: nil)
    present(viewControllerInXib, animated: true)
}
```

To navigate via `UINavigationController` you should use this method:

```
@IBAction func handleButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let viewControllerInXib = ViewControllerInXib(nibName: "ViewControllerXibName", bundle: nil)
    if let navigationController = navigationController {
        navigationController.pushViewController(viewControllerInXib, animated: true)
    } else {
        print("Navigation controller unavailable! Use present method.")
    }
}
```