# Why UIViewController is created from same name XIB even though empty constructor is used?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following class

### CalendarViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class CalendarViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

and I have `CalendarViewController.xib` with file owner custom class is `CalendarViewController`.

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/55801259/72437

I thought if I want to create view controller from XIB, I need to perform

```
extension UIViewController {
    static func instanceFromNib() -> Self {
        func instantiateFromNib<T: UIViewController>() -> T {
            return T.init(nibName: String(describing: T.self), bundle: nil)
        }

        return instantiateFromNib()
    }
}

let calendarViewController = CalendarViewController.instanceFromNib()
```

---

However, if I try the following code

```
let calendarViewController = CalendarViewController()
```

I notice that `calendarViewController` is created from XIB! (Because it contains all the UI components from XIB)

---

I also notice that, if I remove `CalendarViewController.xib` from the project, and run same code

```
let calendarViewController = CalendarViewController()
```

again, then the view controller will not created from XIB.

---

May I know, why `UIViewController` is created from same name XIB even though empty constructor is used?

Comment: Because `init(name:bundle)` with `nil` name will call  default `init()` at some point, AND see the doc of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621487-nibname or it's even described in `init(name:bundle:)`

Comment: But this doesn't explain why init will read from "CalendarViewController.xib", as the string value "CalendarViewController.xib" is not passed into init

Comment: What if init for UIViewController is in fact `init{ return [super initWithNibName:nil: bundle: nil];}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CalendarViewController.init()` / `CalendarViewController()` internally invokes - `init(nibName: String?, bundle: Bundle?)`.

It is clear that you have not specified any value for `nibName`. So `nibName` value is `nil` in your case.

Let's move on to the [UIViewController.init(nibName:bundle:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621359-init) docs. This section in the **Discussion** is of our interest.

> If you specify `nil` for the `nibName` parameter and you do not override the [loadView()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview) method, the view controller searches for a nib file as described in the [nibName](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621487-nibname) property.

1. `nibName` is `nil` in your case.
2. You have not added any implementation for `loadView()` in your subclass.

This leads us to [UIViewController.nibName](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621487-nibname) docs -

> **Discussion**
>
> This property contains the value specified at initialization time to the `init(nibName:bundle:)` method. The value of this property may be `nil`.
>
> If you use a nib file to store your view controller's view, **it is recommended that you specify that nib file explicitly when initializing your view controller**. However, **if you do not specify a nib name, and do not override the loadView() method in your custom subclass, the view controller searches for a nib file using other means**. Specifically, it looks for a nib file with an appropriate name (without the .nib extension) and loads that nib file whenever its view is requested. Specifically, it looks (in order) for a nib file with one of the following names:
>
> If the view controller class name ends with the word ‘Controller’, as in MyViewController, it looks for a nib file whose name matches the class name without the word ‘Controller’, as in MyView.nib.
>
> It looks for a nib file whose name matches the name of the view controller class. For example, if the class name is MyViewController, it looks for a MyViewController.nib file.

The point is - if you don't specify anything for `nibName` AND you have not implemented `loadView()` for your `UIViewController` subclass - system automatically tries to look up a matching nib file in app bundle resources.

1. If it finds one, it will attach that view to your `UIViewController.view` instance.
2. If it doesn't find one, it creates an empty `UIView` instance and attach that view to your `UIViewController.view` instance.